# Help understanding Datasets, Datatables and Excel files

Tags: excel, dataset, datatable, ole

I need to write a C# program that will search and match specific data in several different excel documents, each of which will likely be about 30 pages long. I have seen that there are several ways to access excel data from within my program. For example I could create an instance of an excelapp, open each workbook and access the info using the Excel classes methods from the COM Excel Object Library. I have read that this technique is slower and more clunky. The other way is to open an OLE connection to the excel file and then bring the data into a datatable or dataset. I believe with either technique I can use LINQ expressions to get and find what I want out of the documents. So what technique do you think is the best. If I import the data into a datatable/dataset would that consume a lot of system memory? Is that bad practice? I guess that's what datatables are for right!?!

Comment: how did you end up? I have a similar problem: my c# program should read many spreadsheets and write the data into a ms sql database.

Answer (score 0):

Is the data constantly being updated?

If it is not, using a DB might speed up and simplify things.